# Deleting Class Object Instance Contained in Two Dicts in Python

Tags: python, class, object, dictionary

I'm looking for a convenient way to remove an instance of a class object which is contained in two dictionaries. When I delete the object instance from one dict, I should automatically be deleted in the second dict. Is this anyhow possible?

```
class node():

    def __init__(self, vID):
        self.vID = vID

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.vID)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.vID == other.vID

class structure():

    def __init__(self):
        self.point_index_a = {}   
        self.point_index_b = {}

    def add_point(self,x,y):

        x_object = node(x)
        self.point_index_a[x_object] = None
        self.point_index_b[x_object] = None

    def a_iter(self):

        for k,v in self.point_index_a.iteritems():
            print k,v      

    def b_iter(self):

        for k,v in self.point_index_b.iteritems():
            print k,v

mg = structure() 
mg.add_point(1, 8)
mg.add_point(3, 4)

# point index a
for k,v in mg.point_index_a.iteritems():
    print k,v
# point index b
for k,v in mg.point_index_b.iteritems():
    print k,v

to_del = mg.point_index_a.iterkeys().next()
del to_del

# point index a, object to_del still exists in both dicts
for k,v in mg.point_index_a.iteritems():
    print k,v
# point index b
for k,v in mg.point_index_b.iteritems():
    print k,v
```

Comment: I'd suggest making the deletion an instance method of `structure`.

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for your reply. I just tried your suggestion, unfortunately it didn't work. Could you elaborate or even provide an example based on my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement as follows:

```
class structure():

    ...

    def remove(self, point):
        del self.point_index_a[point]
        del self.point_index_b[point]
```

Comment: Hmm, I get it now, as long it is contained in one dict I have to remove them from both individually, just removing it from point_index_a won't suffice. I was hoping that it will be deleted from point_index_b as well. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: The other option is to use your own `dict`-like class for `point_index_a` and `_b`, that implements `del` with the behaviour you want, but that would be much more complex.

Comment: Ah, ok, sounds pretty sophisticated for a beginner like me, feel free to pseudo code some hints for me, if you feel like it and have time ;)